# Computing Mahalanobis Distance Between Set of Points and Set of Reference Points

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization, linear-algebra

I have an n x p matrix - mX which is composed of n points in R^p.

I have another m x p matrix - mY which is composed of m reference points in R^p.

I would like to create an n x m matrix - mD which is the [Mahalanobis Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) matrix.

D(i, j) means the [Mahalanobis Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) between point i in mX, mX(i, :) and point j in mY, mY(j, :).

Namely, is computes the following:

```
mD(i, j) = (mX(i, :) - mY(j, :)) * inv(mC) * (mX(i, :) - mY(j, :)).';
```

Where mC is the given Mahalanobis Distance PSD Matrix.

It is easy to be done in a loop, is there a way to vectorize it?

Namely, is the a function which its inputs are mX, mY and mC and its output is mD and fully vectorized without using any MATLAB toolbox?

Thank You.

Comment: Could you add your loop-based solution and some realistic values for n,m and p to your question? At least the ideas I have to vectorize it are much less memory efficient as a temporary variable of size m x n x p would be created. Would this fit into the memory?

Comment: Assume it would fit. I just need the fastest code.

Comment: What values for n,m,p are realistic for your problem? Vectorizing is not the only technique to increaze the performance, maybe something else or a combination is the best solution.

Comment: Daniel, thank you for your interest. I want to have a vectorized code. Think there's unlimited memory so the size doesn't matter. I had the "Loop" code to begin with. I want a vectorized code and then I will test which one is superior in which cases.

Comment: I'm not sure that I have properly understood the problem, but it seems to me that you can compute eigenvalue decomposition of `mC`, and then transform all the points into the space where `mC` is diagonal. As a result, computing distance between two points would take *O(p)* instead of *O(p^2)* time. Also, this code can surely be vectorized by SSE/AVX intrinsics, but I cannot say anything about MATLAB.

Comment: @stgatilov, Go ahead, I would like to see that. Use "Pseudo" code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Assuming *infinite* resources, here's one vectorized solution using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and `matrix-multiplication` -

```
A = reshape(bsxfun(@minus,permute(mX,[1 3 2]),permute(mY,[3 1 2])),[],p);
out = reshape(diag(A*inv(mC)*A.'),n,m);
```

**Approach #2**

Here's a comprise solution trying to reduce the loop complexity -

```
A = reshape(bsxfun(@minus,permute(mX,[1 3 2]),permute(mY,[3 1 2])),[],p);
imC = inv(mC);
out = zeros(n*m,1);
for ii = 1:n*m
    out(ii) = A(ii,:)*imC*A(ii,:).';
end
out = reshape(out,n,m);
```

Sample run -

```
>> n = 3;  m = 4;   p = 5;
mX = rand(n,p);
mY = rand(m,p);
mC = rand(p,p);
imC = inv(mC);
>> %// Original solution
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:m
        mD(i, j) = (mX(i, :) - mY(j, :)) * inv(mC) * (mX(i, :) - mY(j, :)).'; %//'
    end
end
>> mD
mD =
      -8.4256       10.032       2.8929       7.1762
      -44.748      -4.3851      -13.645      -9.6702
      -4.5297       3.2928      0.11132       2.5998
>> %// Approach #1
A = reshape(bsxfun(@minus,permute(mX,[1 3 2]),permute(mY,[3 1 2])),[],p);
out = reshape(diag(A*inv(mC)*A.'),n,m);  %//'
>> out
out =
      -8.4256       10.032       2.8929       7.1762
      -44.748      -4.3851      -13.645      -9.6702
      -4.5297       3.2928      0.11132       2.5998
>> %// Approach #2
A = reshape(bsxfun(@minus,permute(mX,[1 3 2]),permute(mY,[3 1 2])),[],p);
imC = inv(mC);
out1 = zeros(n*m,1);
for ii = 1:n*m
    out1(ii) = A(ii,:)*imC*A(ii,:).';  %//'
end
out1 = reshape(out1,n,m);
>> out1
out1 =
      -8.4256       10.032       2.8929       7.1762
      -44.748      -4.3851      -13.645      -9.6702
      -4.5297       3.2928      0.11132       2.5998
```

---

Instead if you had :

```
mD(j, i) = (mX(i, :) - mY(j, :)) * inv(mC) * (mX(i, :) - mY(j, :)).';
```

The solutions would translate to the versions listed next.

**Approach #1**

```
A = reshape(bsxfun(@minus,permute(mY,[1 3 2]),permute(mX,[3 1 2])),[],p);
out = reshape(diag(A*inv(mC)*A.'),m,n);
```

**Approach #2**

```
A = reshape(bsxfun(@minus,permute(mY,[1 3 2]),permute(mX,[3 1 2])),[],p);
imC = inv(mC);
out1 = zeros(m*n,1);
for i = 1:n*m
    out(i) = A(i,:)*imC*A(i,:).';  %//'
end
out = reshape(out,m,n);
```

Sample run -

```
>> n = 3; m = 4; p = 5;
mX = rand(n,p);    mY = rand(m,p);     mC = rand(p,p);  imC = inv(mC);
>> %// Original solution
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:m
        mD(j, i) = (mX(i, :) - mY(j, :)) * inv(mC) * (mX(i, :) - mY(j, :)).'; %//'
    end
end
>> mD
mD =
      0.81755      0.33205      0.82254
       1.7086       1.3363       2.4209
      0.36495      0.78394     -0.33097
      0.17359       0.3889      -1.0624
>> %// Approach #1
A = reshape(bsxfun(@minus,permute(mY,[1 3 2]),permute(mX,[3 1 2])),[],p);
out = reshape(diag(A*inv(mC)*A.'),m,n);  %//'
>> out
out =
      0.81755      0.33205      0.82254
       1.7086       1.3363       2.4209
      0.36495      0.78394     -0.33097
      0.17359       0.3889      -1.0624
>> %// Approach #2
A = reshape(bsxfun(@minus,permute(mY,[1 3 2]),permute(mX,[3 1 2])),[],p);
imC = inv(mC);
out1 = zeros(m*n,1);
for i = 1:n*m
    out1(i) = A(i,:)*imC*A(i,:).';  %//'
end
out1 = reshape(out1,m,n);
>> out1
out1 =
      0.81755      0.33205      0.82254
       1.7086       1.3363       2.4209
      0.36495      0.78394     -0.33097
      0.17359       0.3889      -1.0624
```

Comment: Wow! Going to try it now.

Comment: I think your fully vectorized solution gives the transpose of mD. Am I right? Thank You. Could you explain the fully vectorized solution?

Comment: The output from these solutions would be of size `n x m`, i.e. number of rows in `mX` x number of rows in `mY`. So, it should be same as `mD`. Here's a sample run - http://pastebin.com/V9K6Mjdf

Comment: Yes. I made a mistake in my code, it should have been `mD(j, i) = (mX(i, :) - mY(j, :)) * inv(mC) * (mX(i, :) - mY(j, :)).';`. If you could add what would you change (Don't delete how it is now, just add) I would be grateful. I +1 your answer. I want more people to answer. since you are the first I will mark you in few days. Thank You!!!

Comment: @Drazick Could you edit your question to reflect that. I would edit my answer accordingly after your edit?

Comment: @Divkar, that's the thing, I'd rather have both of them online. Hence if you could add "In the case of..." It would be great. Thank You.

Comment: @Drazick Added the solutions for the alternate code.

Comment: Regarding the alternative solution #Approach 1, I don't think that reshaping with m instead of n will do. The Transpose is the solution, yet doing it that way won't yield the transpose. Unless I'm missing another change.

Comment: @Drazick Think there was a typo. Check out the just added sample runs?

Answer (score 2):

#### Reduce to L2

It seems that Mahalanobis Distance can be reduced to ordinary L2 distance if you are allowed to preprocess matrix `mC` and you are not afraid of numerical differences.

First of all, compute Cholesky decomposition of `mC`:

```
mR = chol(mC)      % C = R^t * R, where R is upper-triangular
```

Now we can use these factors to reformulate Mahalanobis Distance:

```
(Xi-Yj) * inv(C) * (Xi-Yj)^t = || (Xi-Yj) inv(R) ||^2 = ||TXi - TYj||^2
where:  TXi = Xi * inv(R)
        TYj = Yj * inv(R)
```

So the idea is to transform points `Xi`, `Yj` to `TXi`, `TYj` first, and then compute euclidean distances between them. Here is the algorithm outline:

1. Compute `mR` - Cholesky factor of covariance matrix `mC` (takes *O(p^3)* time).
2. Invert triangular matrix `mR` (takes *O(p^3)* time).
3. Multiply both `mX` and `mY` by `inv(mR)` on the right (takes *O(p^2 (m+n))* time).
4. Compute squared L2 distances between pairs of points (takes *O(m n p)* time).

Total time is *O(m n p + (m + n) p^2 + p^3)* versus original *O(m n p^2)*. It should work faster when *1 << p << n,m*. In such case step 4 would takes most of the time and should be vectorized.

#### Vectorization

I have little experience of MATLAB, but quite a lot of SIMD vectorization on x86 CPUs. In raw computations, it would be enough to vectorize along one sufficiently large array dimension, and make trivial loops for the other dimensions.

If you expect `p` to be large enough, it may probably be OK to vectorize along coordinates of points, and make two nested loops for `i <= n` and `j <= m`. That's similar to what @Daniel posted.

If `p` is not sufficiently large, you can vectorize along one of the point sequences instead. This would be similar to solution posted by @dpmcmlxxvi: you have to subtract single row of one matrix from all the rows of the second matrix, then compute squared norms of the resulting rows. Repeat `n` times (
or `m` times).

As for me, *full vectorization* (which means rewriting with matrix operations instead of loops in MATLAB) does not sound like a clever performance goal. Most likely partially vectorized solutions would be optimally fast.

Comment: This is a great idea, really! Thank You.

Comment: Now all we need is the most efficient way to calculate the L2 Distance between each item of 2 sets of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution that eliminates one loop

```
function d = mahalanobis(mX, mY)

    n = size(mX, 2);
    m = size(mY, 2);
    data = [mX, mY];
    mc = cov(transpose(data));

    dist = zeros(n,m);
    for i = 1 : n
        diff = repmat(mX(:,i), 1, m) - mY;
        dist(i,:) = sum((mc\diff).*diff , 1);
    end
    d = sqrt(dist);

end
```

You would invoke it as:

```
d = mahalanobis(transpose(X),transpose(Y))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without any loop at all? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I came to the conclusion that vectorizing this problem is not efficient. My best idea for vectorizing this problem would require m x n x p x p working memory, at least if everything is processed at once. This means with n=m=p=152 the code would already require 4GB Ram. At these dimensions, my system can run the loop in less than a second:

```
mD=zeros(size(mX,1),size(mY,1));
ImC=inv(mC);
for i=1:size(mX,1)
    for j=1:size(mY,1)
        d=mX(i, :) - mY(j, :);
        mD(i, j) = (d) * ImC * (d).';
    end
end
```

Comment: OK, Yet could you offer the vectorized form? Thank You.